# Creating a client/server iOS 5 app

Tags: ios, ios5

I am creating an iOS 5 app for work that will be connecting to a CRM that I developed using PHP and MySQL. I understand most of the theory behind how the app will receive data from the server, it will call a web page which will connect to the database and return data either via JSON or XML. From what I understand most people like JSON and now it seems iOS5 now support JSON so I will probably use that. 99% of the data on this app will be retrieved from the server.

Is there anything that I should look for when developing this app? This will be my first app and I'm sure I will have a lot of learning experiences from it.

Are there any tutorials/podcasts/videos online that specifically deal with what I am trying to build? Videos would definitely help out a lot. Preferable something newer that deals with iOS5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to dive deep in NSURLConnection, you can just use an easy and effective library AFNetworking
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking

It let's you make any type of request, parse responses and failures. Really easy to use.

But, you can try to get into the NSURLConnection though. Then you'll every line of your code)
It's well discussed in Apple's docs
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html